# Vue router with webpack basic example

Tags: javascript, frameworks, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to create a really basic VueRouter example so I can understand how things are working better.

I have the following example:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

window.Vue = Vue;
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import Message from './components/Message.vue';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    routes: new VueRouter({
        '/': {
            component: Message
        }
    })
})
```

Message.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="">Message</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    }
</script>
```

But nothing seems to show and I'm not sure what I'm missing. I figure I need render but I'm not really sure what object i'd be rendering.

What have I left out?

Comment: actually, you just forgot to add "path" as a key for '/'. it should be  like "{path:'/',component:Message}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things wrong here.

First, routes is an array of objects.

```
const routes = [
  {path: "/", component: Message}
]
```

Second, for clarity, define your router outside of the Vue definition.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})
```

In your Vue definition, the router *must* be called `router`.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
})
```

Finally, in your template for `#app`, you'll need a `<router-view></router-view>`.